# MongoDb Schema Structure

Tags: mongodb, schema, categories

I have a collection named 'Category' with this structure:

```
{
 "CategoryID" : 1,
 "ParentID" : 0,
"Name" : "Sample Cat"
}
```

And another collection which will be using this category

```
{
 "DocumentID" : 1,
 "CategoryID" : 1,
 "DocumentName" : "Doc XPXSAX"
}
```

The problem with this design is that when is that I cannot use it to make a live search which will show me the document as

**Doc XPXSAX found in Sample Cat**"(along with category name without using join)

Also I cannot embed the documents inside the `Category` collection (as an array in one of the fields) as I am expecting the number of documents to go up to 50k.

What alternate schema design will enable me to incorporate an efficient search functionality without using hacks imitating joins ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you dislike an application-level join, why not embed the categories inside the document documents?

```
{
    "DocumentID" : 1,
    "category" : {
        "ID" : 1,
        "Name" : "Sample Cat",
        "ParentID" : 0
    },
    "DocumentName" : "Doc XPXSAX"
}
```

Keep the category information you need for display in the document document. Information you need more rarely can live in the category document and be found with a second query or application-level join.